# RecyclerView display earlier than retrofit gets all data

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I use retrofit to get data for displaying in recyclerView. But there are a lot of data and recyclerView displayed earlier than all data will be get. So, at the screen I get empty list. My code:

```
class CatsViewModel constructor(private val catsRepository: CatsRepository) : ViewModel() {
private var job: Job? = null
private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
    onError("Exception handled: ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
}
val citiesList = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun refresh() {
    fetchUsers()
}
private fun fetchUsers() {
    loading.value = true
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler).launch {
        val response = catsRepository.getAllCities()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
             citiesList.value = response.body()?.data?.get(0)

            } else {
                onError("Error : ${response.message()} ")
            }
        }
    }

}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    job?.cancel()
}
```

---

```
class CatsRepository constructor (private val retrofitService: APIService) {

suspend fun getAllCities() = retrofitService.getCitiesList(RequestModel("germany"))
}
```

---

```
class CatsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CustomCityAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private lateinit var viewModel: CatsViewModel
private lateinit var cityAdapter: CustomCityAdapter
lateinit var binding: CatsActivityBinding
private val citiesList = arrayListOf<String>()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = CatsActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.cats_activity)

    val retrofitService = APIService.getInstance()
    val mainRepository = CatsRepository(retrofitService)

    cityAdapter = CustomCityAdapter(this)
    binding.usersList.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    binding.usersList.setItemAnimator(DefaultItemAnimator())
    binding.usersList.adapter = cityAdapter


    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        CatsViewModelFactory(mainRepository)
    ).get(CatsViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.refresh()
    observeViewModel()
}
private fun observeViewModel() {
    viewModel.citiesList.observe(this, Observer {countries ->
        countries?.let {
            binding.usersList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       citiesList.add(it)
                cityAdapter.setCities(citiesList)
            }
    })
```

Comment: Use notifydatasetchanged after setting cities.

Comment: Don't use notifyDataSetChanged after setting cities ^^ that's terribly bad UX advice. What is the real question here? Do you not want to show the list until data is available? if the data is asyncrhonous and you offer a List<T> as a result from the repository, then you naturally can only show the list once you have it, if you want to start displaying elements as soon as they are available, then it really depends on your Repository exposing a Flow of T items and your ViewModel (or Use-Case) mapping/transforming it to a list that keeps growing, then passing this onto a ListAdapter.

Comment: Otherwise, you're going to still need a "loading" state in your Fragment/Recyclerview since asynchronous work will always be async by nature, no matter "how fast it is".

Comment: What does `retrofitService.getCitiesList(RequestModel("germany"))` return exactly? How's the signature of that. Is that a List of countries? Then depending on what your exact question is ("display data earlier than retrofit gets it") is tied to changing the endpoint to be an open socket, have pagination, or use some "buffer" in-between. And that cannot be answered in a single question here, as it would require you to do a lot of homework. If your endpoint returns partial data, then you can start producing it in the Repo and the VM preparing it for a ListAdapter and `submitList(...)`.